# Explain GPU NVIDIA execution time

Tags: c++, architecture, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I have written simple code to sum an array using GPU. I use 1D grid and blocks. Each block computes '2 times block size' elements of the array and reduce these elements to 1 value. Then host code will sum the reduced values of these blocks. Here is the code:

```
__global__ void reduceBlksKernel1(int * in, int n, int * out) {
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x * 2 + threadIdx.x * 2;

    for (int stride = 1; stride < 2 * blockDim.x; stride *= 2) {
        if (threadIdx.x % stride == 0) {
            if (i + stride < n) {
                in[i] += in[i + stride];
            }
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    // use 1 thread to write the reduced value to out array
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        out[blockIdx.x] = in[blockIdx.x * blockDim.x * 2];
    }
}
```

I use Google colab and here is the infos of GPU:

[image: GPU info]

I've run some tests with different block sizes:

[image: statistics]

Could someone help me explain why the execution time decreases with more blocks per SM despite the fact that the occupancy number is 100% for all cases? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider this portion of your kernel where "most" of the work is being done:

```
for (int stride = 1; stride < 2 * blockDim.x; stride *= 2) {
    if (threadIdx.x % stride == 0) {
        if (i + stride < n) {
            in[i] += in[i + stride];
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();
}
```

At each pass through the for-loop, let's first ask the question, how many "active" threads are there?  This is given by the first if-test, which is `threadIdx.x%stride==0`.  `stride` starts out as 1, then 2, then 4, and so on.  So the first pass has the full complement of threads, the second pass selects every 2nd thread, the 3rd pass selects every 4th thread, and so on.

Now let's ask the question, for a given threadblock size, how many *average* active threads do we have for this for-loop, across all iterations.

Finally, let's build a table for the above questions, showing the average active threads, for each threadblock configuration, and also considering the multiplicative factor of having multiple threadblocks resident.  The first average in that table would be computed like this:

```
 1024+512+256+128+64+32+16+8+4+2+1 = 2047/11 = ~186 active threads (average)
```

And for this case there can be only 1 threadblock resident, because Turing has a maximum complement of 1024 threads per SM.  What would that table look like for the other cases?

```
threads/block    average per block   number of blocks resident  average per SM
1024             186                 1                          186
512              102                 2                          204
256              56.8                4                          227
128              31.9                8                          255
```

So you can see that using smaller threadblocks, but more of them, at least for this range and this portion of the analysis, results in more average active threads per SM.  Effectively the SM is consuming higher memory traffic, on average, and therefore is getting this memory-bound workload done more quickly.

So what should we do?

My recommendation would be to precede your reduction operation with a grid-stride loop.  You can get an idea of this by reviewing the [canonical parallel reduction material](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf).  In that material, note the introduction of the [grid-stride loop](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/) at reduction #7.   The idea is to choose the number of threadblocks to just fill your SMs, and use a grid stride loop to efficiently load "all" your data.  This moves the data loading and a portion of the reduction to a very efficient code configuration, while reserving the less-efficient sweep style reduction to a hopefully smaller portion of the overall work.  This will minimize the amount of kernel time spent in the sweep phase, minimizing the effect of threadblock sizing on performance variability.

Of course, even with the above suggestion, if you are going for the last ounce of performance, you may wish to evaluate your code at various threadblock configurations for best performance.  This kind of "ninja-tuning" suggestion is applicable to nearly any GPU code.

As an aside, your reduction methodology here, using only global memory, is not what I would recommend (refer to the linked canonical material for a better approach), but that doesn't seem to be the thrust of your question.

Comment: This is a really helpful answer and materials. Thank you!